# What is mean by Events in Artificial Intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence

While learning about Artificial intelligence I came across this topic events, mental events, mental objects, etc... I searched on internet but I can't able to understand the meaning can someone explain this what is mean by events in AI ?

Comment: It depends on the context. Without knowing that, it's impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Often in AI an *event* refers to something happening (being true) at a particular point in time.

This often arises in logic contexts. For example, we may have a logic knowledge base stating

`for all X: USPresident(X) => USCitizen(X)`

(for all objects `X` who are the president of the United States, `X` is a US citizen).

However, the knowledge base above is insufficient if you are reasoning about multiple points in time, because then who is the US president or even who is a US citizen depends on the moment you are talking about. In that case, it may be best to represent the rule as

`for all X, for all t: USPresident(X, t) => USCitizen(X, t)`

(for all objects `X` and for all time points `t`, if `X` is the president of the United States at time `t`, then `X` is a US citizen at time `t`)

In the latter setting a system could potentially reason about the fact that Reagan was president in 1985 but Obama was not, but in 20010 the opposite was true, etc.

This is particularly important in subjects such as [Situation Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situation_calculus) and [Event Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_calculus).

However, "event" is really just an English word and interpreted in many different ways, even within AI. For example, in Natural Language Processing one can work on the "event detection" problem which consists of automatically detecting descriptions of events in English within a document. In any case, those meanings of "event" are normally associated with the idea of something happening at a certain point in time.